# перемещение объекта вверх вниз в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

пишу игру на питоне .
при нажатиях клавишей должно происходить перемещение объекта влево, вправо понятно как, но вверх и вниз  я не понял как указать, чтоб он двигался

```
def update(self):
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_up :
        self.center #здесь нужно вписать указание
    if self.moving_dowm:
        self.center #здесь нужно вписать указание
    self.rect.centerx = self.center
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Задать разные переменные для перемещения по горизонтали и по вертикали, потом прибавлять их к `self.rect.centerx` и `self.rect.centery`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
добавил по совету insolor переменную "self.rect.centery", только теперь не могу понять, как сделать границы для верха и низа.
Ps. методом догадок всё таки смог ограничить края и низа, и верха, я  пытался в строчку "if"  запихнуть "self.screen_rect.height  и self.screen_rect.width ", но уже в отчаянии начал бить в переводчике слова и понял, что я беру не верх, а высоту, в "self.screen_rect..." нужно вписать не "height", а "top" (верх).
Также и с низом, вместо "down"- нужно "bottom". Вот и всё, теперь корабль ограничен со всех сторон :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код добавьте текстом вместо скриншота. Для ограничения сверху/снизу добавьте условия для moving_up и moving_down что если center_y достигло границы, то не изменять координату.

Comment: да, я это понимал, но просто не знал как это реализовать